# Android soft keyboard pushing views

Tags: android, android-layout, view, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

i'm developing a soft keyboard for an android and I faced a problem which I could not solve. The problem is that when I open a keyboard it moves other views incorrectly (see the picture, my keyboard on the left).

[image: This is how my problem looks like]

I have tried multiple solutions that I found on stackoverflow or somewhere else, but they didn't work for me.

I've tried:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

but it didn't change the behavior you see on the screenshot.

So, please help me to solve this problem.

Ps. I know that there are many similar questions where `"adjustResize"` or `"stateHidden|adjustPan"` is offered, but it doesn't work for me.

P.p.s screenshot is taken in android 6.0.1.

Thanks.

Comment: #Fedor Tsyganov : Did you try `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya he is creating a custom keyboard so how you gonna adjust pan in that

Comment: @Fedor add your code too as my keyboard doesn't show this behaviour

Comment: @VivekMishra do I need to include my code from the class that extends InputMethodService or the one that extends KeyboardView?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes I did and it doesn't work

Comment: @FedorTsyganov both  like this 
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener

Comment: @VivekMishra please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840627/rejusting-ui-with-candidateview-visible-in-custom-keyboard) to my question. You need to use this code in your class that extends `InputMethodService`:

```
@Override
public void onComputeInsets(InputMethodService.Insets outInsets) {
     super.onComputeInsets(outInsets);
     if (!isFullscreenMode()) {
        outInsets.contentTopInsets = outInsets.visibleTopInsets;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply switch your activity's *windowSoftInputMode* flag to "**adjustPan**". Remove **adjustResize**.

```
 <activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
   </activity>
```

Comment: Please read the description, solution "android:windowSoftInputMode" doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your layout xml? It may help to understand the reason

Comment: Or try with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing". Even if you tried windowsSoftInputMode with other options, I think it can solve the problem.

Comment: "adjustNothing" won't help and it's not a problem in xml file, because i'm developing a keyboard, not a usual application and it works a bit differently than a normal app, for example, there is no activity tag in manifest

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your layout with scrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    .
    .
    .
    .
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the android:windowSoftInputMode can work, but like this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Try it.